# Ignore unsupported type error on JSON Marshal

Tags: json, go

Here is my code:

```
func dump(w io.Writer, val interface{}) error {
    je := json.NewEncoder(w)
    return je.Encode(val)   
}

type example struct {
    Name string
    Func func() 
}

func main() {
    a := example{
        Name: "Gopher",
        Func: func() {},
    }
    err := dump(os.Stdout, a)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

The program will panic with `json: unsupported type: func()`

My question is, how can I encode ANYTHING into json, ignoring those the encode cannot handle. For example, the above data structure, I want the output to be: `{"Name": "Gopher"}`

IMPORTANT: for the dump funtion, its value is an `interface{}`, i.e. don't know what kind of data it will receive, so tricks like `json:"-"` is **not** what I want.

If in case that the data passed to dump() is not marshal-able, e.g. `dump(func(){})`, it is perfectly acceptable to just return empty string.

**EDIT after two years:**

The answer provided by @TehSphinX has this piece of code which I want to avoid:

```
func (s example) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(struct {
        Name string
    }{
        Name: s.Name,
    })
}
```

the reason is: in `func dump(w io.Writer, val interface{}) error`, the **`val`** is ANY code, i.e. code NOT written by me, could be any open source code, or even data types I don't have access to its source code.

Comment: Why is `json:"-"` not what you want? It has nothing to do with `val interface{}` or whatever.

Comment: @mkopriva the reason I do not want json tag is that the function I want to write is a **utility** function used for debugging. I do NOT want to add any requirement for the data to be dumped.

Comment: In that case I would say that you're out of luck, the values that the json encoder accepts have to satisfy a number of requirements, which are documented, for it not to blow up. I can see 3 options: 1. use something other than json, 2. write your own json encoder, 3. before passing the value to the encoder use the `reflect` package to build a `map[string]interface{}` out of the original value, leaving out fields that aren't encodable, and then pass the map to the encoder.

Comment: If your goal is data inspection and debugging, then the [spew](https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew) package may be of help.

Answer (score 8):

### JSON tags (the correct way)

Is this what you are looking for: [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ELjv0U7hHFA)

You can use field tags to give json instructions on how to handle your struct. See also [encoding/json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) for more info on the options you have.

-- edit --

It does not matter that val is of type `interface{}`. `json.Marshal()` will reflect on it anyway and find out what type it is. It is the programmers job to set the correct `json` tags on all structs he/she wants to `dump`.

### Custom Marshal function (another here not necessary way)

You can also write a custom MarshalJSON function to do marshalling of every type however you like: [custom marshalling playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PCFm_nFIrUM)

### Your own json Marshaller (have it your way)

If you don't like the way golang handles json marshalling you could always write your own marshalling function doing all the reflection youself.

Comment: Since you obviously did't like my answer I improved on it showing you all the options you have.

Comment: write my own marshaller **will** solve the problem, at a _high_ cost I'd avoid.    I am just hoping a sort of call back func/interface in the standard library to handle unknown types.  Since my purpose is solely data inspection/debugging. I will stick with fmt.Printf("%+v", ...) unless a viable json one is available :-)

Comment: The `viable json` is already available. You just don't want to use it the way it is build. And I don't get why.

Comment: I think I have a very similar issue to the original question and I can answer why `encoding/json` package doesn't work here. I'm developing a thing on Google App Engine, so my logging is in JSON format, which is then nicely parsed and displayed in the UI. And the problem I have is that sometimes I want to log the whole `http.Request`, but I can't just serialize it as is because it contains at least one `func` field. I can dump whole request as a string, but then log viewer will not parse it and won't allow filtering on sub-fields.

Comment: I'd create a function called `getRequestData` and extract all the relevant data from the `http.Request` to a struct of your own design and log that. e.g. the body must be read from the request first anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json.RawMessage](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage). It can be used to delay JSON decoding or precompute a JSON encoding.

Comment: can you show an example how can json.RawMessage be used in ENCODING? thanks.

Comment: this is good to know such usage of json.RawMessage. However, it is not what I want. I want to handle ANY data structure without knowing its structure, NOT to design a universal data structure that can be dumped, or to design a "wrapper" structure to convert a data structure to be dumped. If I would design such a data strucuture, using json:"-" is simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to log the entire struct, you can do this.

```
func dump(w io.Writer, val interface{}) error {
    je := json.NewEncoder(w)
    return je.Encode(val)
}

type example struct {
    Name string
    Func func()
}

func main() {
    a := example{
        Name: "Gopher",
        Func: func() {},
    }
    type _example struct {
        example
        Func interface{}
    }
    err := dump(os.Stdout, _example{example: a})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

This is an example of logging the entire http.Request.

```
type _Request struct {
    *http.Request
    GetBody interface{}
    Cancel  interface{}
}
j, err := json.MarshalIndent(_Request{Request: r}, "", "    ")
```

Answer (score 0):

To Quote the comment from  Cerise Limon

> If your goal is data inspection and debugging, then the spew package may be of help.

Spew is wow-cool!! https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew

part of dump of an HTTP request:

```
(*x509.Certificate)(0xc00016c100)({
 Raw: ([]uint8) (len=947 cap=960) {
  00000000  30 82 03 af 30 82 02 97  a0 03 02 01 02 02 10 08  |0...0...........|
  00000010  3b e0 56 90 42 46 b1 a1  75 6a c9 59 91 c7 4a 30  |;.V.BF..uj.Y..J0|
  00000020  0d 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7  0d 01 01 05 05 00 30 61  |...*.H........0a|
  00000030  31 0b 30 09 06 03 55 04  06 13 02 55 53 31 15 30  |1.0...U....US1.0|
  00000040  13 06 03 55 04 0a 13 0c  44 69 67 69 43 65 72 74  |...U....DigiCert|
```